# Green Card EAD vs H1B

Tags: usa, working-visas, immigration, greencard, h1-visa

I'm a bit confused with my status and deadlines to find a job. I'm currently within my H1B day #40 of grace period after my job loss. I also have Green Card EAD (that I got through employment EB1-b with 180 days been passed- still valid until 10 months, AoS interview in 2 months).

So how much time do I have to find a job? I'm a bit confused. Is it 20 days (until the end of H1B), or 2 months (until my AoS interview)?

My assumption was that now that I have EAD, it means I'm like a GC holder; I am authorized to work and no specific deadline to find a job unless otherwise I-485 is denied or USCIS asks to do so. Please advise.

Comment: @user102008 appreciate your great opinions, as before!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to continue working on H1b, you should find a company that sponsors H1b's to file a petition for you before your status ends at the end of the 60 days.

However, you don't have to have status to stay in the US or to work. You can stay in the US because you have a pending I-485, and you can work on your EAD even if you find work after your H1b status ends (or if you find a company that doesn't sponsor H1b's). So you don't *have to* find a job before your 60-day H1b grace period ends, but if you find a job after your grace period ends, you will be working on EAD and won't have a status. The downside to not having status is that if your I-485 is denied, you will have to leave the US immediately.

Comment: OK, that's a relief! Thanks. I don't know why my lawyer said I "have to" have a job by end of my grace period.

Answer (score 0):

This is a comment from another user for a similar question. Hoping it is correct.

"You remain in status for 60 days after leaving job in H1b and other work statuses; this is just a rule for the status and is unrelated to I-485 or immigration. Since you have I-485 pending, you can stay in the US even if you go out of status, i.e. even after 60 days, and **you can work on your EAD even if you go out of status**. As far as I know, there is no specific time limit for you to find another job to continue your I-485; you just have to have a job if USCIS asks you to submit I-485 Supplement J (which they can do at any time)."